# PowerShell -match vs -like

Tags: regex, powershell, match

Reading [official docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) it's obvious that PowerShell `-match` operator is more powerful than `-like` (due to regular expressions). Secondly, it seems ~10 times faster according to this article https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/powershell-operators-like-match.

Are there specific cases when I should prefer `-like` instead of `-match`? If there not, why at all should I use `-like`? Does it exist because of historical reasons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this explanation from [*Differences Between `-Like` and `-Match`*](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_like.htm#Differences_Between_-Like_and_-Match)

> In a nutshell, if you are thinking, '*I am probably going to need a wildcard to find this item*', then start with `-Like`.  However, if you are pretty sure of most of the letters in the word that you are looking for, then you are better off experimenting with `-Match`.
>
> Here is a more technical distinction: `-Match` is a regular expression, whereas `-Like` is just a wildcard comparison, a subset of `-Match`.

So, whenever you are not sure what character classes, i.e. digits, letters, punctuation, etc., can there be inside, when you just want to match *any character*, you should be using `-Like` with its *wildcards*.

When you know there must be a digit at the start followed with 1+ sequences of a colon followed with alphanumeric characters up to the end of the string, use `-Match` with its powerful [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: Heh, that article says wildcards are a subset of regexs. Try putting the pattern `*` through a regex and see what happens :)

Comment: You tell me to use a quantifier alone in a regex pattern? I know what will happen without checking that in the online tester.

Comment: No, I didn't mean that, sorry. I was just commenting on the article: it says that wildcards are a subset of regexes, when obviously they are not. They are less powerful than regexes, but they're not a subset.

Comment: I see, but I think the word "subset" here means that they are also *patterns*, just these are somewhat different patterns. They also *match* specific chunks of texts, just they cannot match *regular* grammars.

Comment: I understand. I was just commenting on the correctness of the claim.

Comment: This answer may be legitimate (and upvote), but it still doesn't convince me to use `-like` instead of `-match` because one can easily imitate a wildcard with `".*"` in regex?

Comment: @Bad It's up to personal preference, functional requirements and very little else.

Comment: If you know you need to match some string that starts with or ends with some known literal, `-Like` is a more readable choice. Some people are crazy about readability. Often, wildcards are faster than complex regex that is prone to catastrophic backtracking especially with `.*` subpatterns.

Answer (score 8):

I've never seen `-match` test that much faster than `-like`, if at all.  Normally I see `-like` at about the same or better speed.

But I never rely on one test instance, I usually run through about 10K reps of each.

If your're looking for performance, always prefer string methods if they'll meet the requirements:

```
$string = '123abc'    

(measure-command {
for ($i=0;$i -lt 1e5;$i++)
 {$string.contains('3ab')}
}).totalmilliseconds

(measure-command {
for ($i=0;$i -lt 1e5;$i++)
 {$string -like '*3ab*'}
}).totalmilliseconds

(measure-command {
for ($i=0;$i -lt 1e5;$i++)
 {$string -match '3ab'}
}).totalmilliseconds

265.3494
586.424
646.4878
```

Comment: Indeed, `-like` is faster than `-match` here (my results 149.6149, 215.0783, 284.6945)

Comment: Just as for completionist testing: If there is no match the -match way can be faster than -like. So if you know the not-matches will be significant more than the matches test again. But .Contains .StartsWith etc always win.

Answer (score 2):

You should prefer `-like` when your comparator string is a dos-style filename wildcard. If you have a cmdlet that is designed to look like a "standard" windows command line application, then you can expect file name parameters to include dos-style wildcards.

You might have a grep-like cmdlet that takes a regex and a list of files. I can imagine it being used like this:

```
> yourMagicGrepper "^Pa(tt).*rn" *.txt file.*
```

You would use `-match` when working with the first parameter, and `-like` for all other parameters.

In other words: it depends on your functional requirements.