# Powershell GCI Recursive Depth Stops Working When Adding Include Parameter

Tags: powershell, recursion, get-childitem, powershell-5.0

I have what I'm assuming to be a simple question. I have a large block of code that I have written. In short, it downloads a dynamic list of file names and extensions, imports a csv with the roots of every one of our shares, and compares the files to find matches.

```
$Directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Depth 2 -Include $ExtList -Force
```

Super simple, right? Except the depth parameter isn't working. It recursively searches through every single level. If I do this:

```
$Directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Depth 2  -Force
```

The Depth parameter works perfectly and it only searches through the two levels. If I don't include recurse or depth, it works as expected by searching only the top level. The only difference is that I'm removing the -Include parameter.

$Path is a variable like \server\root\
$ExtList is an array of filenames

Again, they both work individually, but not together.

I need to have both the depth and include parameters in here. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong, or if it's a glitch?

Edit ---------------------------

Doing "Where-Object" I tried this:

```
$Directory = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Depth 2 -Force | Where-Object {$_.Extension -like $ExtList}
```

And... nothing happens. For testing, this script takes about 10 minutes to successfully run on a good day, it finished in less than 1 second. (715ms to be exact)
When I go into debugging, it's like there is nothing being piped into the where-object.

[image]

EDIT------

The $ExtList setup looks like this:

```
@((Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://fsrm.experiant.ca/api/v1/get").content | convertfrom-json | % {$_.filters})
```

That will get you the exact list and format that I'm using.

$Path pulls from a csv file that looks like this:

[image]

This CSV has over 3000 different shares in it. I know it's weird, yes I have to do it this way for our infrastructure.

Comment: Can you try piping into `Where-Object` instead of using an `-Include` switch?  In [several](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684178/powershell-5-get-childitem-literalpath-doesnt-work-with-include-anymore) [other](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) locations, it seems like people are having trouble with some of the `-Depth` switch usage.

Comment: As @gravity suggested, pipe to `Where` instead. You shouldn't lose any performance, since the `-Include` argument gets all results from the provider, and then filters down to the specified inclusions.

Comment: So. I'm not as familiar with Where, but when I add in `| Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $ExtList -or $_.Extension -eq $ExtList}`, nothing happens. When I go into the debugger, it's like the variable doesn't get pulled through. @gravity @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Don't use `-eq` - [use either](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295016/powershell-match-vs-like)  `-match` or `-like`.  You're comparing strings to each other, and even if they are literally the same (ie: `.ext` and `.ext`), you'll still often see `-eq` fail... (Click the link for a breakdown of the differences between `-match` and `-like`.  I prefer `-match` for exact comparisons I know to be static.

Comment: @gravity I edited the post to include what I'm doing... maybe you can steer me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Since it took a while to clarify, and I 'guessed' at your `$ExtList` and `$path` setup, please further [edit] your answer once more and show those two assignments as well, if my answer doesn't work for you.  ;)

Comment: Your additional edits are not sufficient to continue, unfortunately.  Please provide a [mcve], for us, to avoid time being lost further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching  to run on a Windows Server 2012 R2 box, the depth parameter works with include. It seems to have been a bug with the version that I was on.